# SQL find all records from one table, but only the most recent record from a linked table

Tags: sql

I am looking to select all records from my **userrecords** table and then find the corresponding most recent record from my **checkins** table.

I need to do this so that I can display whether the user is checked-in or checked-out for the current day and campus.

The outdatetime is a NULL value when the user is currently checked-in, and the query should take into account the current date so that only checkin records for the current date are considered.

My table setup is like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `userrecords` (
`userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userlevel` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `suspended` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastcheckdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `maincampus` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastlogin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `staffid` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userid_UNIQUE` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AU

CREATE TABLE `checkins` (
  `recordid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `campusid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `indatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `outdatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recordid`),
  KEY `campusid_idx` (`campusid`),
  KEY `userid_idx` (`userid`),
  CONSTRAINT `campusid` FOREIGN KEY (`campusid`) REFERENCES `campus` (`campusid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `userid` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `userrecords` (`userid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

My query is so far:
`SELECT userid,firstname,surname,email,lastcheckdate FROM userrecords WHERE userlevel=0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select ur.*, c.*
from userrecords ur left join
     (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by indatetime desc) as seqnum
      from checkins c
     ) c
     on ur.userid = c.userid and ur.seqnum = 1;
```